# Shortcut with Ctrl does't work in gvim

Tags: vim, shortcut, ctrl

I'm trying to make shortcut for Vim, to make it more suitable for Esperanto when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>:

`imap <C-ĝ> <C-w>  "Delete last word`

It works fine with `vim` but with `gvim` it just puts `ĝ` character.

How can I make it work with `gvim`?

Edit: I figured out that it works with `vim` even without mapping.
But I still can't make it work against `gvim`.

Comment: What does `:imap` say in gvim?

Comment: Do you `:set encoding` somewhere? This must be done consistently and _before_ the mappings.

Comment: Also `:scriptencoding` should be correct.

Comment: Jens, `:imap` listed mappings including `i <C-ĝ> <C-w> `

Comment: Ingo Karkat,  Alex Kroll: `enconding` is set to `utf-8`. Before mapping is executed.  `scriptencoding` is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same problem with Cyrillic letters. For example, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ы</kbd> in insert mode results in just <kbd>Ы</kbd>. I did some searching and .. looks like it is a GVim-specific problem.

Hopefully, there are other GUIs and Qt version works much better. It treats <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ы</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> as other X applications do (<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ы</kbd> share same key on my keyboard). xev shows same result. So, take a look at http://gitorious.org/vim-qt.